# Правильность расстановки запятых

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Здравствуйте, проверьте, пжл., правильность расстановки запятых:

В трудных условиях, он, с помощью напарника, взял на себя несение этой обязанности, которая сильно его обременяла.

Answer (score 1):

В трудных условиях он, **с помощью напарника**, взял на себя эту обязанность, которая сильно его обременяла.

В данную структуру предложения лучше вписывается **уточняющее обстоятельство с обособлением**.

Answer (score 0):

В трудных условиях, он, с помощью напарника, взял на себя несение этой обязанности, которая сильно его обременяла.
Я думаю, что это сложноподчинённое предложение, состоящее из главного, ничем не осложнённого, и придаточного определительного. Он - подлежащее,  в трудных условиях  - обстоятельство, с помощью напарника - дополнение. В главном ничего обособлять не надо. Ставим вопрос к придаточному: обязанности какой?  - которая сильно его обременяла.Таким образом, я абсолютно согласна с Niemand, что нужна одна запятая - перед союзным словом "которая".